# Woocoomerce Insertar Productos con categorías vía PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas porque inserta la categoria del producto, pero no lo asigna al producto relacionado. Os dejo aqui debajo lo que estoy haciendo.

```
$post = array(
    'post_title'        =>  "Mi_Producto",
    'post_content'      =>  "Mi_contenido",
    'post_date'         =>  $fecha,
    'post_status'       =>  "future",
    'post_type'    => "product",
    'post_name'    => "Mi_Producto"      

);

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);

$term = get_term_by('name', 'Juguete', 'product_cat');

wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

**P.D.** *Lo que deseo hacer es asociar la categoría al producto, lo que me esta haciendo solamente es Insertar la categoría, sin asociarlo al producto.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que lo estás haciendo bien pero según la documentación de Wordpress (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by), $term->term_id es un string y puede que te falle por eso, prueba a forzarlo como int:

```
wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, (int)$term->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

Si esto falla, ¿has probado a forzar el id de categoría directamente en el código? por ejemplo:

```
wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, 1, 'product_cat');
```

Comment: Le he añadido como menciona el ID de la categoria a pelo, y sigue todavía sin asociarlo al producto que se inserta en la base de datos, debe de haber algo que se esta pasando por alto y no se que puede ser.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, tenias toda la razón @track3r. El problema que tenia es que mas abajo hacia otra inserción en la categoría y esto machacaba mi consulta, Thank´s you :)